# How to control JPA Column names in Map

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

The entity Construction

has following map:

```
    @Column(name = "paper_FK")
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "construction_FK"), joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "construction_FK", referencedColumnName = "construction_FK"), name = "ConstructionPaperTracks", inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "paper_FK"))

private HashMap<Integer, Paper> tracks_field = new HashMap<Integer, Paper>();
```

Due to my database design guidelines the table ConstructionPaperTracks
should have the columns construction_FK, position and paper_FK.

JPA works with construction_id, position and paper_id.

How can i specify the column names?

best regards

Heiko

Comment: i think the problem is you also define a constraint with same name of column (construction_FK); try to keep construction_FK in the `@JoinColumn` and call the `@ForeignKey` something else

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understand "JPA works with construction_id, position and paper_id."

Anyway, I believe the mapping will be as below:

```
@Entity
public class Construction{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "construction_id")
    //specify a generation strategy
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ConstructionPaperTracks", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "construction_FK"), 
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "paper_FK"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "position")
    private HashMap<Integer, Paper> paper;
}
```

You need to specify the `@MapKeyColumn`, the documentation for which states that:

> If the map key is for a ManyToMany entity relationship or for a
>   OneToMany entity relationship using a join table, **the map key column
>   is in a join table**

For the joinColumn and inverseJoinColumn the referencedColumn names will default to the primary key column of the referenced tables (construction_id, paper_id) so you don't have to specify these.

Comment: JPA works with construction_id, position and paper_id means, it works, when i use these column names - position is the right column name, now i need  construction_FK and paper_FK

Comment: doesn't work means, when the column names are construction_FK instead of construction_id and paper_FK instead of paper_ID - my mapping does not work - JPA complains at deployment time.

Comment: JPA complains at deployment time - and expects the column names, that i don't want - construction_id and paper_id. when i name them in the table as i want, hibernate throws an exception at schama validation phase.

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is. You will need to edit your question to make it clearer and post all relevant information.